# Disagree with review audit

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I gave a 'No action needed' verdict to an answer that suggested the OP upgrade to a newer version of RazorGenerator and that this had helped the answerer. According to the audit, this should have been a 'Not an answer':

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/9913788

I disagree that this could not be an answer to the problem OP is having (or someone else finding the question in the future). I agree that it could have been answered more elaborately, but I don't think it clearly falls into the 'Not an answer' category (especially since the failed audit took away my review privileges for 2 days). Is there any way to dispute this?

Comment: You failed that audit correctly. Link only answers aren't considered OK.

Comment: But it wasn't only a link

Comment: Just because the answer contains a link does not make it a 'Link only' answer

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I'm not sure I see what you mean on this one.  Unless you're seeing a revision I'm not seeing, the answer paraphrased, without the link is, "Update to the latest version of the package. It worked for me".  Is it a low quality answer? Yep. Is it link only? I don't think it fits the [definition](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/305827). Reading the OP's self answer, updating packages solved their problem.

Answer (score 8):

This is in the Late Answer queue, not the Low Quality Post queue.  This means that you *shouldn't* have just done nothing.  While the answer doesn't merit deletion as Not An Answer, it *does* have a lot of problems, it's very low quality, and you *should* have acted on that from the late answer queue.

You could have commented on the answer to explain how it could be improved, (such as by including the version at which the package was updated to provide the functionality the OP is looking for, or explaining more about what the problem is and how the proposed solution resolves it).  It could use a bit of editing (it's not awful, but there are some improvements that could be made).

So indicating that the post doesn't merit *deletion* is correct; it's not bad enough to merit deletion, but saying that it doesn't need *any* action is still wrong.